# How to use a .data directive inside a macro

Tags: assembly, x86, macros, masm

```
    write macro msg
      .data 
      string byte msg,0
    endm
```

gives an error "unmatched block nesting: main". Removing .data from above macro doesn't cause this error.

Comment: Defining the macro in a `macros.inc` file and using `include macros.inc` rather than defining the macro in the source code doesn't cause the error.

Comment: There should probably be a `.code` before `endm`.

Comment: I was missing the `.code` inside the macro.Adding `.code` before endm works. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a `.code` directive (even though there is no code) inside the macro just before `endm`. This macro should work:

```
    write macro msg
      .data 
      string byte msg,0
      .code
    endm
```

Comment: I made this answer a community wiki since I wanted to establish an answer from the comments of all users.